# searchskinobjectpreview.js error in DNN7 and ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dotnetnuke

I have created a skin in Dotnetnuke7.0 and added DNN's search option. Search works great in all the browsers except in IE8 when I click on search box it throws a popup error showing "object doesn't support this property searchskinobjectpreview.js". I am not able to resolve this issue since this file is from DNN if i remove this file search option doesn't work in other browsers.

Please let me know if anyone facing same issue and is their any resolution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered not rendering the Search preview if the user is browsing from IE8?

Comment: Sorry No I haven't done that, How do we do that?

Comment: That would require some form of hack, I haven't looked into how. You likely would have to write some JQUERY that looks for the browser type, and then hide some of the DNN code